# WPF style is applied not to all expected controls

Tags: c#, wpf

A ListBox has three items and a custom ItemTemplate. Inside ItemTemplate there is ContentControl which has a custom style. The style is applied only inside the third ListBox item. I expect it to apply in every ListBox item.

```
<Window 
    ...
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Width="500" Height="500">
<Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="items" Type="{x:Type sys:Object}">
        <sys:Object/>
        <sys:Object/>
        <sys:Object/>
    </x:Array>
    <Style x:Key="style" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Border Background="LightBlue"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Green" Margin="5">
                <ContentControl Width="100" Height="100" Style="{StaticResource style}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

[image]

If to define markup for ContentControl directly instead of applying the style, then it works as expected but I prefer to use styles and I want to understand why this happens in case I have the same   problem again.

Do I miss something or is this an issue outside my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the expected way to style a ContentControl.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd334411(v=vs.95).aspx.  Your style should look similar to what is shown there:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentControl">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF000000"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
        <ContentPresenter
            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
            Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

or in your case:

```
<Style x:Key="style" TargetType="ContentControl">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Border Background="LightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
          <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too. I think in this case it is more proper using ControlTemplate than DataTemplate like was suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create `DataTemplate` and use `ContentTemplate` property instead.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="blueBackgroundTemplate">
        <Border Background="LightBlue"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="style" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource blueBackgroundTemplate}" />
    </Style>
<Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped.